# how to set <title> tag from article title with custom menu entry?

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo, metadata

I am searching for a option to use the 
article title as a page title  if I have defined a custom SEF-menu item.

The only way which I have found is to set the page title via the menu item. But this brings in senseless confusion on setting title on multiple places. So I would like to define a configuration, which changes the  to use the article title itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set article title as page title](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/18573/12352) Is this what you are asking?  Or [Joomla 3 - use article title as browser Page title with the menu item title](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15643/joomla-3-use-article-title-as-browser-page-title-with-the-menu-item-title)  And if you enjoy doing a lot of scrolling, there is always [the Joomla Forum](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=662612)

Comment: @mickmackusa seems joomla makes the admins the work really hard. is there no way to configure the required behaviour? The only thing I could find is the forum post to modify the template